# Making multiple searches in a string using scanner or string methods (java)

Tags: java, string, extract, java.util.scanner

I need to extract several integers from a string that looks like this:

22:43:12:45

I need to extract 22, 43, 12, and 45 as separate integers. I need to use string methods or scanner methods to read up until : and extract the 22. Then read between the first : and second : to give me 43, and so on.

I can extract up to the first : no problem, but I down know what to do thereafter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything? Or search?

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] parts = str.split(":");
int[] numbers = new int[parts.length];
```

Iterate over this String array to get an array of integers:

```
int index = 0;
for(String part : parts)
    numbers[index++] = Integer.parseInt(part);
```

Comment: +1 This is the easiest way if the separators (the colon) are the same.

Comment: Is there an easier (even if less efficient) way of doing this? This is for a first semester computer sciences course and we haven't covered things like [], new, or split... Only basic things like next() or indexOf()

Comment: @Wimp then use Scanner class. and use ":" as delimiter in your scans. search for scanner delimiter example.

Answer (score 0):

Make a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) like

```
(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at String.split method . Given a regular expression, this methods splits the string based on that. In your case the regular expression is a ":"

```
String s ="22:43:12:45";
int i =0;
for (String s1 : s.split(":")) {  // For each string in the resulting split array 
     i = Integer.parseInt(s1);
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

The split returns a string array with your string separated. So in this case , The resulting string array will have "22" on the 0th position, "43" on the first position and so on. To convert these to integers you can use the parseInt method which takes in a string and gives the int equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) and [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) methods of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```
String text = "22:43:12:45";
int start = 0;
int colon;
while (start < text.length()) {
    colon = text.indexOf(':', start);
    if (colon < 0) {
        colon = text.length();
    }

    // You can store the returned value somewhere, in a list for example
    Integer.parseInt(text.substring(start, colon)));

    start = colon + 1;
};
```

---

Using Scanner is even simpler:

```
String text = "22:43:12:45";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
scanner.useDelimiter(":");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // Store the returned value somewhere to use it
    scanner.nextInt();
}
```

However, [`String.split` is the shortest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981114/572834).